# How to capture the complete DNS recursive query name server path?

Tags: dns

I'd like to know if there is a way to capture the entire DNS recursive query path? (i.e. When the resolver on my computer sends a UDP query to the local DNS server, the server passes the query through a series of name servers before it reaches the authoritative name server. I want to know every single server along the path.)

Tried nslookup and various DNS lookup tools, but they only gave the authoritative resource record without showing the route leading to this result.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `dns +trace`.

```
$ dig +trace www.stackoverflow.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> +trace www.stackoverflow.com A
;; global options: +cmd
.           10h11m19s IN NS l.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS f.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS b.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS e.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS d.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS m.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS i.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS g.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS k.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS c.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS a.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS h.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN NS j.root-servers.net.
.           10h11m19s IN RRSIG NS 8 0 518400 (
                20190731050000 20190718040000 59944 .
                h37qHHCpVvZ5cw5RCHQs9FiNUc6cYO0bSxDatRwZlnza
                lf7otk/DGAibKrvtmVdE7sePmdh6pA7XcaICyuWKrucG
                SJdNlnwDCSXgZGNjOQL+fI3aU1kczxbvVCpMdSOk8pWS
                eV9Iwz109qBcvDUJB8a8lYxa4Y9BZAONcnmr5yeIiQsy
                UvwWOST6f/pSTAJKMTMFkFC/O5bmi527SglJs1oVx7Oq
                MA+RYx647LF5W/nvRXlKU0FHcWy8GH2pRY3obBr6yg19
                QUHYPX+oCizP65IJDoz3h1sp902lHRDFlsILAk0m6tHK
                KV4QixZYl9l6KoI8QtHYSkOxwwX6FnF2Zw== )
;; Received 525 bytes from 9.9.9.9#53(9.9.9.9) in 79 ms

com.            2d IN NS a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            2d IN NS m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            1d IN DS 30909 8 2 (
                E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459
                588F4A9184CFC41A5766 )
com.            1d IN RRSIG DS 8 1 86400 (
                20190731050000 20190718040000 59944 .
                hmwZHci5TxM6wPVGdaDRKJ5w5554UbLN1cc/W/5Ksb1/
                lZDMmVQKaGPYUP1qss6UqMqkXSbyx2sz5aQbukBQOlkK
                PwG6xFdzjBWw3yNxNQM6/0npP64/EzJ0dBU0qvTfxIeE
                TMSuRtbcPFMsX4PtXlZcsEsnn9xg5uwE1n5fBguGRsOL
                qiMJTpHiv4iq44Ll5Z84D+MX9axzgijkUvY04NVL/CI3
                yN1xtujOQZUFk35XdXN/KfKMRrdLieKp7j6iS/rPp5ph
                At85ZJa0c93fDsPzyQs88qWpnpxd4iy/2e7xCCr5SLp9
                ZNUtmyxyqfnZ4wSJdOZjtZovUj4GyLUy3w== )
;; Received 1181 bytes from 193.0.14.129#53(k.root-servers.net) in 141 ms

stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-358.awsdns-44.com.
stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-1033.awsdns-01.org.
stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 1d IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - (
                CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A
                NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM )
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 1d IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 (
                20190722044529 20190715033529 3800 com.
                QruEtMEx3JMwz1cwK+gArQ3ZkNbCR4x+8ul54fAkec4I
                eN6LvHGTo61mDq5w/D0fzhLIhwXRtbxSpDPspvqYpEys
                6f69kM1U4NzGvTb8/iz7/b0Tes+n3i+Gx0S+/X7ajkvu
                +J6GmVpgsZPIMxpSJjGSLZXtlEB4YyPBprWZsck= )
QJLANLBLFPUKKIO73G776E7389OP43C0.com. 1d IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - (
                QJLBMGGUF1TGTFH7U479EFSNO84B6UPD
                NS DS RRSIG )
QJLANLBLFPUKKIO73G776E7389OP43C0.com. 1d IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 (
                20190725050317 20190718035317 17708 com.
                UrrzTGluj/zP3D4mj/D0WIv3/JkM9XbMPtnGCamyWv3Y
                GQqb7fdUa9+DXzBjTR1XiS7AGtL5DeivPKCMU1FDHv28
                0uFdk/IAUWTGknlAalujtZWlXUSwlCEifAJrqrDK+itv
                sVtWPG1Xf4Oq0yZAcxWeiSC+SX3Tv8fR0m5jBL4= )
;; Received 771 bytes from 192.35.51.30#53(f.gtld-servers.net) in 135 ms

www.stackoverflow.com.  1h IN CNAME stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com.  5m IN A 151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com.  5m IN A 151.101.65.69
stackoverflow.com.  5m IN A 151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com.  5m IN A 151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-1033.awsdns-01.org.
stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-358.awsdns-44.com.
stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
stackoverflow.com.  2d IN NS ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
;; Received 260 bytes from 205.251.193.102#53(ns-358.awsdns-44.com) in 80 ms
```

Then it depends what you mean exactly by capture.
You can also:

- run a network sniffer and record all TCP/53 and UDP/53 packets
- run a local recursive nameserver and switch its logging, and point your request to it, and see the results in the logfiles.

Comment: Great! Going up to the unnamed root and back down into subdomains. This is exactly what I wanted